# Page not being redirected to default error page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have defined in my web.config a default error page:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Erro_Padrao.aspx">
</customErrors>
```

Now, I'm forcing an error in one of my pages to test the error page:

```
Try
    Dim var1 As Integer = 1
    Dim var2 As Integer = 0
    Dim result As Integer = var1 / var2

Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
```

The error occurs but nothing happens.

Anyone?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I am trying this inside a method that is called by a DevExpress' ASPxGridView component. The exception message is not shown in the default .NET yellow error page, but this grid somehow handles the exception and "blocks" the redirection(yeah, the error message is in portuguese):

[image]

If I try to do this in the page_load event, for example, the redirection for the default error page works fine.

Comment: Do you see the standard yellow page instead of your custom page?

Comment: Did you check _Global.asax_ if there is an **application_Error** eventHandler?

Comment: Yes, there is an application_Error event handler. Should I write some code there? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Found an [article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q394737.aspx) describing that under certain circumstances devexpress GridView will catch exceptions. Pls show us **what dataSource gridView uses** and all other **settings made for gridView**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an article on [DevExpress' ASPxGridView](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q273796.aspx) pointing out, that **any unhandled exception within an GridView** will be **catched automatically** and the **CustomErrorEvent** will be raised. See [only documentation of DevExpress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomErrorTexttopic).

> The CustomErrorText event **occurs when any exception is raised** within
>   the ASPxGridView, and allows you to change the error text displayed by
>   default. This can be useful, if you want to localize error messages.